# Having Api endpoints in the Spring boot entry point gives error in Junit test cases

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, microservices

My applications main class is as follows which contains some API endpoints

```
    @CrossOrigin
//(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ContentDemoApplication.class, args);
    }



    @Autowired
//  private FormatRepository formatRepository;

      @GetMapping("/format")
    public List<Format> listFormats() {
        return formatRepository.findAll();
    }
```

I am trying to write a Junit test case for one of my Controller class  which is as follows

```
@RestController
public class TypeController {
@PostMapping("/type")
public Content saveType(@RequestBody TypeDTO typeDTO) {
    return typeServiceImpl.saveType(typeDTO);
}
```

Now I defined a Junit test class for above controller

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = TypeController.class, secure = false)
public class TypeControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private TypeServiceImpl typeServiceImpl;

    @MockBean
    private TypeRepository TypeRepository;

    @Test
        public void testSaveType() throws Exception {
```

Now whenever I run testSaveType()

```
   I get the following error in the console: 

        `019-08-04 13:22:41.913  WARN 25376 --- [           main] `o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'DemoApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'formatRepository'; nested exception is` org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.foo.repository.FormatRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`
    2019-08-04 13:22:41.919  INFO 25376 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2019-08-04 13:22:41.977 ERROR 25376 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

    ***************************
    APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************

    Description:

    Field formatRepository in com.example.foo.DemoApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.foo.repository.FormatRepository' that could not be found.


       Action:
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Field formatRepository in com.example.foo.DemoApplication required a bean 
of type 'com.example.foo.repository.FormatRepository' that could not be found.
```

But why the Spring Boot application class `DemoApplication` would need to inject a repository in its own instance ?
Because you made the Spring boot application a `RestController` too and that it relies on the `FormatRepository` dependency.

You should not declare your spring boot application with a `@RestController` :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {...}
```

It looks that the container try to load that part too during the `WebMvc` test slicing.
Move that bean in its own class :

```
@RestController
public class FormatController {
    @Autowired
    private FormatRepository formatRepository;

    @GetMapping("/format")
    public List<Format> listFormats() {
        return formatRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Make the application class as :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {...}
```

And the dependency requirement issue will leave.

Answer (score 2):

> **`@WebMvcTest`** auto-configures the Spring MVC infrastructure and limits
>   scanned beans to `@Controller`, `@ControllerAdvice`, `@JsonComponent`,
>   `Converter`, `GenericConverter`, `Filter`, `WebMvcConfigurer`, and
>   `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.
>
> **Regular @Component beans are not scanned when using this annotation.**

In this case you need to add:

```
@MockBean
private FormatRepository formatRepository;
```

and stub whatever is needed.

If you want to use this component and its real implementation you need to use `@SpringBootTest` for example.

**Update**

Ideally, you should use `@MockBean` on `TypeServiceImpl`, so the direct collaborator of the controller. Then you would not need to mock the repositories alltogether.

Comment: It should work but an XY issue I think. The OP mixed annotations that are not done to work together on its spring application class.

Comment: Nope. When you use @WebMvcTest, Component, Service and Repository standard annotations are not picked up by the test context so he needs to fix that also

Comment: Indeed. But why the spring boot application class needs to inject a repository in its own instance ?  Because the op mixed two things in it.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski  already tried this '@MockBean
private FormatRepository formatRepository; but same error.

Comment: Yes you are right, completely missed that. But on top of it OP needs to keep in mind how WebMvcTest works in terms of bean management.